# Cannot ready property 'length' of undefined trying to upload file

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to upload a file of whatever file extension. I'm uploading with a post, but when a run the function, it crash with an error: 
**"Cannot ready property 'length' of undefined "**

```
upload(fileToUpload: File): Promise<FileResponse[]> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.http
        .post<FileResponse[]>(this.baseUrl + this.urlUpload, formData, { headers: {'Content-Type': undefined }})
        .toPromise().then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          return response;
        }).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
          return e;
        });
  }
```

This is my back end c#:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("upload")]
        [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
        [RequestSizeLimit(104857600)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
        {

            var fileUploaded = await _fileService.UploadFile(FormOptions, reader);
            return Json(new StandardResult<List<FileResponse>>(HttpStatusCode.Created, fileUploaded).Reply);
        }
```

any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's for this line:

```
{'Content-Type': undefined }
```

Or delete this line or put a generic "type", for example *application/octet-stream*

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

Comment: yes i found that could be that the error, and that's it!!